# How to transpose key/value pairs into table in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

Incoming data ('Key' and 'Value' are the actual names of the fields in the dataset):

```
Key    Value
---    ----- 
A      1.0
B      2.0
C      3.0
A      4.0
B      5.0
C      6.0
```

Desired output in report:

```
A    B    C
-    -    -
1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Tried so far:

With 'Key' as Column group, and 'Value' as the data, the row headings are correct, but only the first row of data appears in the matrix.

```
A   B   C
-   -   -
1.0 2.0 3.0
(no other rows appear)
```

With 'Value' as row group instead, the data is all sparse in the matrix, since it is treating every change in any field a new group:

```
A   B   C
-   -   -
1.0
    2.0
        3.0
4.0
    5.0
        6.0
```

Comment: Best way is to change the output of the dataset to the desired format in the report.   And the best way to do that is with a PIVOT.

Comment: trying not to change at source, as it serves multiple clients. I thought the whole point of the Tablix was that it does pivoting?

Comment: The tablix should allow you to group by the Key-field in a Column Group, while showing details as Row Group. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your PIVOT requirement is a little unusual; PIVOTs usually involve aggregating data, but you want to keep the data discreet, I guess based on the order that it appears in the table?  Not sure how that's going to be done since row order of data isn't expected to be reliable without an ORDER BY.  Is there another column that you are using to ORDER BY?  In other words, how should SQL know that A=1.0 should be on the same row as B=2.0, and not B=5.0?

Comment: @TabAlleman - i can assure that the order is correct as it comes out of the data source. To answer, everything is one row until key 'a' is reached again. This is coming from an XML dictionary (the result of an Web Service call) and unfortunately, SSRS is flattening the structure and losing some hiearchy information

Comment: P.S. many thanks for you interest and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a column to your data set, which support you for grouping:

if your dataset is like

```
select KEY, VALUE from TABLE
```

you can change it into

```
select KEY,
  VALUE,
  row_number() over (partition by KEY order by KEY) as RN 
from TABLE
```

then in the tablix, you can group by RN

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am hesitant to include new values at the data level since this will affect other consumers, but if there are no better ideas, I will mark as answer - thanks!

Comment: any chance I can mimic that row_number behavior as a calculated field within Report Builder? (so I can leave original data set alone?)

Comment: as far as i now, the calculated field does not support this rownum over partition.